# In GDB is there an option to stop execution when the variable of our interest is set or modified?

Tags: gdb

I have a large codebase, I want to know when a particular variable of our interest is getting set.
Since there are hundreds of placed in the huge codebase it is getting set and since I am new to the codebase I am not aware of the code flow as well. It has become difficult to trace when the variable is getting set.

So there is an option inn GDB to watch on a particular variable which is of our interest and the GDB stops the flow or intimates about the modification of the variable.

Comment: See [watchpoints](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Set-Watchpoints.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `watch` when you don't know where *exactly* in the code some expression will be evaluated, or `break` when you know the line number/symbol. gdb will stop the execution of the program when the expression evaluates to true.

The syntax for watch is `watch [expression]`.

The syntax for break is `break [line number/symbol] if [cond]`

As [ssbssa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1983398/ssbssa) pointed out, you may refer to the watchpoints section of the gdb manual [here.](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gdb/html_node/gdb_29.html)

Comment: Thanks... I knew about break but not about 'watch'. This will do the trick for me.